# Exclude binary files from git ls-files

Tags: git

I'm trying to exclude binary files from `git ls-files`. I've defined a file (similar to .gitignore) defining my patterns.

When I run the command looking for ignored files, I see the correct files listed:

```
git ls-files --exclude-from=.ls-files-exclude --ignored

lib/jconn4.jar
lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar
```

Yet when I run the command looking for all non-excluded files, they're still listed.

```
git ls-files --exclude-from=.ls-files-exclude
```

Am I missing something? I need to exclude these files, they *cannot* be present.

Comment: What are the contents of `.ls-files-exclude`?

Comment: Yes, for some reason `--exclude-from` doesn't seem to work for me either, and unfortunately I couldn't find example/evidence that it is actually working for anyone as documented.

Answer (score 0):

The `--exclude` and `--exclude-from` options of the `ls-files` work much the same as `.gitignore`. You can only ignore or exclude files that are untracked. If they are showing up in your output, this means that you must have added them and committed their addition before.

To stop tracking a file, you can use `git rm --cached`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That makes sense. They're meant to be in the repo itself I'm just trying to run some reporting commands, so will need to exclude them some other way.

Comment: @helion3 Note that `git rm --cached` doesn't actually remove the file itself, rather it's record from Git's internal database. The file will still be there and you can then correctly ignore it.